# recursion in variadic template function of different argument types

Tags: c++, arguments, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

consider the following piece of code

```
template <int INDEX>
void foo() {  } // termination version

template <int INDEX, typename Arg, typename... Args>
void foo(Arg head, Args... args) {

    if (INDEX == 0) {


        cout << head << endl;
    }

   else {


        foo <INDEX-1 > (args...);

   }

}

int main() {

   foo<1> (1, 3.1415);

   return 0;
}
```

the code compiles and outputs 3.1415 as expected.

however, the following simple code compiles fine but always outputs 1. do you have any fix for this?

```
template <int INDEX>
void foo() {   } // termination version

template <int INDEX, typename Arg, typename... Args>
Arg foo(Arg head, Args... args) {
    if (INDEX == 0) {

        return head;

    }

    else {


        foo <INDEX-1 > (args...);

    }



}



 int main() {

 cout<<foo<1> (1, 3.1415,"Test!");

return 0;
}
```

in other words, how can I recursively call a variadic templated function with different argument types?

Comment: Enable your compiler warnings please.

Comment: Not all paths return... -> ill formed code.

Comment: `return std::get<Index>(std::forward_as_tuple(args...));` ?

Comment: Do you know how to fix this? the idea is that a function could process a bunch of unrelated arguments and return some results as the argument type.

Comment: Thankx. I know about tuple, but I want to implement few lines myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1 Problems with your approach

### 1.1 Missing `return` in `foo<1>`

Make sure you understand how a `return` from a nested call works. Your `foo<1>` calls `foo<0>` which returns its (`foo<0>`'s) first argument back to `foo<1>`. But your `foo<1>` does not care about `foo<0>`'s return because it called `foo<0>` like this:

```
else {
    foo<i-1>(args...);// `i-1` becomes `0`
}
```

The compiler knows you have a problem here: Which value should `foo<1>` return after it got the return from `foo<0>` (which has been ignored)? It has to return a value of the same type as its first argument, but it never returns before reaching its closing `}`.

As pointed out in the comments, you should turn on compiler warnings to detect problems like these. In this case, [`-Wall` (GCC documentation on warning options)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wall) is [sufficient for GCC and clang to warn you (online demo)](https://godbolt.org/g/UDpZmU), but there are more warnings available. If your filename reads `main.cpp` and the closing `}` is found line 23, column 1, the compiler warning could read

```
main.cpp: In function ‘Arg foo(Arg, Args ...) [with int INDEX = 1; Arg = int; Args = {double, const char*}]’:
main.cpp:23:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]


 }
 ^
```

### 1.2 Return type must be known at compile time

You might attempt to fix your code by passing the return value from `foo<0>` up the stack:

```
else {
    return foo<i-1>(args...);// NOTE: type of return value depends on `foo<i-1>`
}
```

However, that fails because `foo<1>` has been declared to return a value of the same type as its first argument:

```
template<int i, class Arg, class... Args>
Arg foo(Arg, Args... args) {// <--------- NOTE: must return a value of type `Arg`
```

## 2 Fix for your own recursive implementation

### 2.1 C++17 and above

With C++17 you can use `auto` as return type together with `constexpr if` to implement the recursion as follows:

```
template<size_t i, class T0, class... Ts>
auto foo(T0 v0, Ts... vs) {
  static_assert(i < 1u + sizeof...(Ts));
  if constexpr(0u == i) return v0;// <------ NOTE: must be `if constexpr` (C++17)
  else return foo<i-1u>(vs...);
}
```

### 2.2 C++14 and above

With C++14 you can also use `auto` as return type, but `constexpr if` is not available. The workaround is a well-known idiom and uses specialization of a class templates that "implements" the recursion logic:

```
template<int i>
struct foo_impl {
  static_assert(i > 0, "the case `i == 0` requires a specialization");

  template<class T0, class... Ts>
  static auto get(T0, Ts... vs) {
    return foo_impl<i-1>::get(vs...);
  }
};

template<>
struct foo_impl<0> {
  template<class T0, class... Ts>
  static auto get(T0 v0, Ts...) {
    return v0;
  }
};

template<int i, class... Ts>
auto foo(Ts... vs) {
  static_assert(i >= 0 && i < sizeof...(Ts), "index range: [0, size)");
  return foo_impl<i>::get(vs...);// forward to "implementation"
}
```

### 2.3 C++11 and above

With C++11 you would need to specify trailing return types which is a bit tedious. See [max66's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46838649/2615118) for details.

## 3 Final recommendations

- Enable and analyze compiler warnings (`-Wall` is an absolute minimum).
- Once you are familiar with these techniques, do not implement this yourself. Instead, learn and use standard solutions like `std::tuple`.
- Use compile-time recursion with caution. It may significantly increase your compilation time.

Comment: than you. very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible (in C++11 and C++14, at least) develop a `foo()` of this type because you don't know the correct return type.

If you don't want use `std::tuple`, I suggest to develop a type traits to extract the n-th type and manage `foo()` via SFINAE.

The following is a possible solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <std::size_t, typename...>
struct indexType
 { using type = int; }; // the type of the foo() without argument

template <std::size_t I, typename I0, typename ... Is>
struct indexType<I, I0, Is...>
 { using type = typename indexType<I-1U, Is...>::type; };

template <typename I0, typename ... Is>
struct indexType<0U, I0, Is...>
 { using type = I0; };

template <std::size_t I, typename ... Args>
using indexType_t = typename indexType<I, Args...>::type;


template <std::size_t>
int foo ()
 { return 0;  } // termination version: a return type is needed


template <std::size_t I, typename Arg, typename... Args>
auto foo (Arg const & head, Args const & ...)
   -> typename std::enable_if<I == 0U, Arg>::type
 { return head; }

template <std::size_t I, typename Arg, typename... Args>
auto foo (Arg const &, Args const & ... args)
   -> typename std::enable_if<I != 0U, indexType_t<I-1U, Args...>>::type
 { return foo<I-1U>(args...); }

int main ()
 {
   std::cout << foo<1U> (1, 3.1415, std::string("Test!")) << std::endl;
   std::cout << foo<2U> (1, 3.1415, std::string("Test!")) << std::endl;
   std::cout << foo<3U> (1, 3.1415, std::string("Test!")) << std::endl;
 }
```